# MongoDB Query, get document only if there is results in lookup

Tags: mongodb

I have collection of events and collection of devices:

Events:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a3e9f2613e8867c1300002a"),
"AS_CloudsID" : 397,
"TerminalsID" : 1,
"TABLE_NAME" : "Products",
"ItemsID" : 43,
"UpdateNew" : 0,
"RepType" : 1
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a3eafa813e886e407000029"),
"AS_CloudsID" : 377,
"TerminalsID" : 1,
"TABLE_NAME" : "Products",
"ItemsID" : 14812,
"UpdateNew" : 0,
"RepType" : 1
}
```

Devices:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a3ea0999c1d80a468094d34"),
"DateCreated" : ISODate("2017-12-23T18:29:45.569Z"),
"cloudID" : 397,
"terminalID" : 1
}
```

When I am executing this query:

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([
{
 $lookup:
   {
     from: "devices", 
       let: {
            cloudID: "$AS_CloudsID",
            terminalID: "$TerminalsID",
         },
         pipeline: [
            {
               $match: {
                  $expr: {
                     $and: [
                        {
                           $eq: [
                              "$terminalID",
                              "$$terminalID"
                           ]
                        },
                         {
                           $eq: [
                              "$cloudID",
                              "$$cloudID"
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
     as: "Devices"
     }
 }
 ])
```

I get good results but I only need the events that have Devices, so I need to add some where: `Devices.length > 1` How I can do it?

Right now I get documents (from event collection) with empty array of Devices.

Comment: An event occurs on a device.   How can it occur on not-a-device?   Beyond that, where does Devices.length come into play?   This implies that events-to-devices yields an array.   Do this:  Edit your question with, say, 4 events and 2 devices, leaving out the fields that are not important for the query.  Then describe your desired output and we'll help you get the right query.

Answer (score 1):

Use $match pipeline after $lookup to get events only with devices.

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate(
    [{
            $lookup: {
                from: "devices",
                let: {
                    cloudID: "$AS_CloudsID",
                    terminalID: "$TerminalsID",
                },
                pipeline: [{
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [{
                                    $eq: [
                                        "$terminalID",
                                        "$$terminalID"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    $eq: [
                                        "$cloudID",
                                        "$$cloudID"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }],
                as: "Devices"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
               Devices: { $size: { $gt: 0 } }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Thank You, Very much, it seems good something more now, i get error "$size needs a number", when i change the $size value to number its work good.